# MutationObserver не работает

Tags: javascript

Суть проблемы: на странице (https://vk.com/feed) изначально скрипт расширения срабатывает, срабатывает при листании ленты, а так же при её обновлении. Но, если переходить между "Мессенджером" или другими вкладками Вконтакте и вернуться обратно на новостную ленту, скрипт перестает работать.

```
   const config = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    };
    
    
    const callback = async function(observer) {
        removeElementsByClass(REPLIES);
        removeElementsByClass(REPLIES_HEADER);
        removeElementsByClass(RECOMMEND_GROUPS);
        removeElementsByClass(MAYBE_FAMILIAR_HEADER);
        removeElementsByClass(MAYBE_FAMILIAR_MAIN);
        removeElementsByClass(MAYBE_FAMILIAR_SHIT);
    };
    
    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
    
    observer.observe(document.documentElement || document.body, config);
```

Пробовал в target вписывать просто document - ситуация та же.

Comment: Во первых приложите пожалуйста МИНИМАЛЬНЫЙ, воспроизводимый код, нажав на CTRL+M в редакторе вопроса. Во вторых у меня вопрос: зачем вы используете ключевое слово `async` если в самих ф-иях ничего асинхронного не делаете?

Comment: Не проще через CSS "удалить" элементы? Если задача только в этом.

Comment: Я не уверен, но не лучше ли будет для таких целей отслеживать изменение `window.location` через эвент `popstate`, вместо изменения DOM в `document`?

Comment: Спасибо @Neverm1ndo

Comment: @MadBo, проблема решилась?

Comment: @Neverm1ndo, к сожалению, добавилась новая проблема: при отслеживании popstate ощущение, как будто на ленте выключаются скрипты, а именно: лента новостей перестает подгружать новые посты. При перезагрузке страницы (нажатием F5) посты подгружаются в штатном режиме.

Comment: @Neverm1ndo
`const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(document, config);
window.onpopstate = callback`

Comment: @MadBo так `MutationObserver` вроде вообще можно убрать и лучше добавьте отдельный слушатель через `window.addEventListener('popstate', callback)`. VK наверняка использует этот слушатель, а вы его перезаписываете, вместо добавления отдельного.

Comment: @Neverm1ndo к сожалению, `window.addEventListener('popstate', callback)` срабатывает только один раз, а затем скрипт уже не отслеживает появление новых классов. Из-за этого я не удалял `MutationObserver` после вашего первого ответа. Видел на просторах интернета, что кто-то реализовал отслеживание через `timer`, но мне кажется есть более красивое решение проблемы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137542/discussion-between-neverm1ndo-and-madbo).